# Teradata BTEQ conditional not working as expected

Tags: conditional-statements, teradata

I have a rest. where I need to check
if a teradata table exists. If yes then delete the records
If no then create the table as per DDL

The issue is that ..both the statements are getting executed and the conditions I want to run are not successfully run

```
select * from doc.tablesV
where database = DATABASE_NAME 
and table = TABLE_NAME ;   

.if activitycount = 1 then .GoTo del_tab ;   
.if activitycount = 0 then .GoTo create_tab ;
.LABEL del_tab ;   
delete  table DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
.LABEL create_tab;
create multisite table ...;
```

In the log I see this message
For the first run (when no table exists)

```
activity count =0
.label del_tab
skipped
.label create_tab
Go to create_tab
```

del_tab command is executed (though it says skipped)
and it fails (as no table exists)

Is there any mistake in my conditional logic? or Is there any limitation to the conditional logic in BTEQ?
Thanks
Pari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of activity count , use count(1) to check if the record is present in dbc.tables. Then continue with your logic. The below piece of code should work.

```
INSERT INTO table_cnt
(
cnt_var
)
select count(1) from doc.tablesV
where database = DATABASE_NAME 
and table = TABLE_NAME ; 

.if cnt_var = 1 then .GoTo del_tab ;   
.if cnt_var = 0 then .GoTo create_tab ;
.LABEL del_tab ;   
delete  table DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
.LABEL create_tab;
create multisite table ...;
```